# Repeated rows in Crystal Report

Tags: vb.net

When I use this code, I get repeated rows in my Crystal Report. I can't use distinct because I have an OLE object.

```
SELECT  PT.PT_Code, PT.age_sex2, PT.fullname2, Ptsense.PT_Date, DR.Dr_Name, Ptsense.sample, Ptsense.G, Ptsense.coun, Ptsense.comm, Ptsense.organism, Ptsense.lowsens, resist.resis, labdetails.labnme, labdetails.labspecial, labdetails.labadress, labdetails.labphone, labdetails.labtime, labdetails.labprint, labdetails.labnameenglish, labdetails.labspecialenglish, labdetails.lablogo  
FROM labdetails, resist  
INNER JOIN ((PT INNER JOIN Ptsense ON PT.PT_Code = Ptsense.PT_Code)  
INNER JOIN DR ON PT.DR_Code = DR.Dr_Code) ON resist.PT_Code = Ptsense.PT_Code  
WHERE (((PT.PT_Code)={0}) AND ((Ptsense.PT_Date)=#{1}#));"
```

Comment: If you get many rows and you need only one, what is the field that separates it from the others? Filter your query on that. Or only ask for 1 row - `Select Top 1...`

Comment: Your question is very clear as to what is being repeated and what data you want to show.  You can create a group section for the rows which are repeating.  If you do not include a details section you will only get one row in the group.